# rspec testing a controller post changing my params from symbols to strings and breaking my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my controller spec I am doing this:

```
it "should create new message" do
  Client.should_receive(:create).with({:title => 'Mr'})
  post 'create' , :client => {:title => "Mr" }
end
```

... and in my controller I am doing ...

```
def create
  client = Client.create(params[:client])
end
```

However this is failing with the following error message :

```
  expected: ({:title=>"Mr"})
       got: ({"title"=>"Mr"})
```

I'm wondering why this is happening and how to get it to work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because you are passing a symbol and not a string. This should fix it :

```
it "should create new message" do
  Client.should_receive(:create).with({:title => 'Mr'})
  post 'create' , :client => {"title" => "Mr" }
end
```

Here's a blogpost about it: "[Understanding Ruby Symbols](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2005/08/19/understanding-ruby-symbols)"

Comment: do you know if its possible to make the post pass it in as a symbol as I want to create the hash from a machinist blueprint and they return symbols not strings

Comment: I don't think you can do such a thing, it's just the way POST works

Answer (score 2):

@ssmithone you could use [ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess) to pass params as symbols instead of strings. This should work:

```
it "should create new message" do
  Client.should_receive(:create).with({:title => 'Mr'}.with_indifferent_access)
  post 'create', :client => {:title => "Mr"}
end
```