# Rspec: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I'm trying to create a very simple blog using Rails, for my own education. It's the first Rails app I've ever created other than from working through tutorials.

So far I just have a very simple model where each post has only a string for the title and a string for the content. Everything works fine and as expected in the browser, but I can't get the tests to pass.

Here's are the failing test in my Rspec code (spec/requests/post_spec.rb):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Posts" do

  .
  .
  .

  describe "viewing a single post" do

    @post = Post.create(title: "The title", content: "The content")

    before { visit post_path(@post) }

    it { should have_selector('title',    text: @post.title) }
    it { should have_selector('h1',       text: @post.title) }
    it { should have_selector('div.post', text: @post.content) }

  end

end
```

This gives me the same error message for all 3:

```
Failure/Error: before { visit post_path(@post) }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil}
```

So it seems to me the problem is that the line @post = Post.create(...) is creating a post without an id, or else it's not saving the post to the test database correctly. How do I fix this? And am I going about this the right way in the first place, or is there a better way I could be creating the test post/testing the page?

This is only a problem in testing. When I view a single post in the browser everything looks fine. The Posts controller is: (I have edited this since posting the original question)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Post successfully created!"
    end
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And here's the Post model in its entirety:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title

  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :title,   presence: true
end
```

config/routes:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :posts

    root to: 'posts#index'
end
```

app/views/posts/show.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, @post.title) %>

<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

<div class="post"><%= @post.content %></div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the routes please?

Comment: do you have routes for show ?

Comment: Just edited the question to include them.

Comment: ok will you please confirm that when you are creating a new post, your post is created ? because it seems that you have nil id

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. I can create a new post within the console, then view that post in the browser at the URL localhost:3000/posts/2 (or whatever number). I don't know how to confirm that a new post is created within the tests.

Comment: can you put your controller in full on here aswell please

Comment: Done. There's not much else in there though!

Comment: Where are your new and create actions? how can you create a post without these?

Comment: Oops, copied from an older version of the file, sorry. Updated the question again. The tests still fail with those methods.

Comment: Try `let!(:post) { Post.create(title: "The title", content: "The content") }`, `before { visit post_path(post) }`

Comment: Thanks Kien but that doesn't work either. It gives me an error message "undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: you should also change `@post.title`, `@post.content` to: `post.title`, `post.content`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've done that and I now get the error message "       expected css "title" with text "The title" to return something" and similar error messages for the other two. I don't know why this is happening: those tags are definitely on the page! I've added my show.html.erb code to the question too.

Comment: put three `it` into **describe** block, like: `describe "show post page" do it ... it... it... end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance variable needs to go into the before block. (the test is trying to goto /posts/:id/show and params[:id] in this case is nil as @post hasnt been created)

try:

```
before do
    @post = Post.create(title: "The title", content: "The content") 
    visit post_path(@post)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems your new and create actions are empty?? Try

```
def new
@post =Post.new
end

def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
if @post.save
  redirect_to posts_path, :notice => " Post successfully created."
end
end
```

and then your view for new needs to have a form_for @post

You cant create a new post without this and only when this is successful your posts will e assigned ids

Comment: Okay, I added these exact methods to my posts controller and I created a very simple form_for at app/views/posts/new.html.erb. When I create a post at localhost:3000/posts/new, it works, and I can view the newly created post at (e.g.) localhost:3000/posts/3. But the tests still fail with the exact same error messages as before!

Comment: see if this post is of any use to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183372/rspec-testing-a-controller-post-changing-my-params-from-symbols-to-strings-and-b

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to put your 'before' stuff outside the test? This works for me:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Posts" do

  before(:each) do 
    @post = Post.create(title: "The title", content: "The content")    
  end

  describe "viewing a single post" do
    it "should show the post details" do
      get post_path(@post) 
      response.status.should be(200)
      # do other tests here .. 
    end
  end
end
```